# Как увеличить ограничение в 32767 на Top (и другие метрики) компонентов (это необходимо, например, для scrollinga Tpanel на TForm)?

Tags: delphi, vcl

В Delphi 6 максимальные размеры метрик компонентов ограничены 32767 как в режиме проектирования, так и при выполнении. Мне необходимо увеличить абсолютный размер Top TPanel при ее прокрутке вверх в режиме выполнения с большим числом расположенных на ней элементов, а именно: `Panel1.Top := -64200` (до -200000).

Comment: Может Вам нужен ScrollBox?

Answer (score 2):

Ограничение накладывает Windows функция перемещения окна `MoveWindow`, которая вызывается для установки `Top, Left, Width, Height` оконных контролов. Как пишут [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466422/createwindow-coordinates-are-limited-to-32767), входные параметры Integer она урезает до SmallInt (-32768..32767). Собственно там и предлагают костыль в виде:

```
procedure MoveWinControl(Control: TWinControl; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ScrollWindow(Control.Parent.Handle, -X, -Y, nil, nil);
  Control.Left := 0;
  Control.Top := 0;
  ScrollWindow(Control.Parent.Handle, X, Y, nil, nil);
end;
```

Дополню. Процедура `MoveWindow` посылает окну сообщения `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, WM_MOVE, WM_SIZE, and WM_NCCALCSIZE`.  Нас интересует `WM_MOVE`, MSDN говорит на этот счет следующее:

> lParam
>   The x and y coordinates of the upper-left corner of the client area of the window. The low-order word contains the x-coordinate while the high-order word contains the y coordinate.
>   xPos = (int)(short) LOWORD(lParam);   // horizontal position
>   yPos = (int)(short) HIWORD(lParam);   // vertical position

В Модуле Messages.pas TWMove объявлен как:

```
TWMMove = packed record
    Msg: Cardinal;
    Unused: Integer;
    case Integer of
      0: (
        XPos: Smallint; // <-----
        YPos: Smallint); // <-----
      1: (
        Pos: TSmallPoint;
        Result: Longint);
  end;
```